# jQuery change handler for Google Maps tooltip

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm using the Google Maps Javascript API in my web application. Custom tooltips displaying forms currently open whenever the user draws a marker/overlay on the map. I want to make one of the forms interactive using jQuery - specifically, I want different form fields to be displayed depending the selection of a radio button at the top of the form. However, my jQuery .change() handler doesn't seem to be firing.

The code where I add the tooltip looks like this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function(circle) {
  var radius = circle.getRadius();
  var center = circle.getCenter();
  var circleForm = "<%= escape_javascript(haml(:tooltip_form)) %>";
  var circleInfoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: circleForm
  });
  circleInfoWindow.setPosition(circle.getCenter());
  circleInfoWindow.open(map);
```

The radio buttons in question are in tooltip_form.haml and are named "group1". At the bottom of the same $(document).ready() block, I then have my jQuery code that looks like this:

```
$("input[name='group1']").change(function() {
  alert("Changed"); // sample code
});
```

However, the handler is not firing when the tooltip appears and I change the radio button selection. I've found that if I add radio buttons named "group1" to the page itself, the handler fires, but when they're in a tooltip that appears after a circle is drawn, the handler won't fire. Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: You can try to use `.input` instead of `.change`